# Facebook API - Realtime insights results?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to create an application which monitors users like data in real time. I know there is a realtime API for subscribing this user feeds and such, but I was wondering if this extends to insights too?

Let us say user x has a website with a like button, I want to use the realtime api to monitor any likes to that page as they happen.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't get the real time data as they are not providing it. They provide the data 48 hours old

See what they are saying

**How long does it take Facebook to process and display Insights data?**

The data that you access through Insights is at most 48 hours old. In the event of a delay, we will announce it on Platform Live Status.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/insights/

Comment: "at most", not "at least" - which would mean data is available before 48h have elapsed?

Comment: I haven't had any facebook insight updates on my app since the end of May, over a week ago.  What is going on over there?  Is Zuck on vacation....you guys are partying it up?